# Spring - What order are the @modelattribute methods called in with multi-action controllers

Tags: spring

I have a controller which has multiple actions and corresponding @modelattribute methods. One of the methods output is a input to the next method. However the value was never getting set. When I debugged, I found that the order in which the methods are called are not what I expected. Is it anyway related to the command name @ModelAttribute("nominationCommand") or the method name. What drives this?

```
@ModelAttribute("awardCommand")
public AwardCommand getAwardList(HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, Model model) {

@ModelAttribute("associateDetails")
public List<AssociateDetailsCommand> getAssociateList (HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session, Model model) {

@ModelAttribute("achievementCommand")
public AchievementDetailsCommand getAchievementDetails(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

@ModelAttribute("departmentCommand")
public List<DepartmentCommand> getDepartmentList(HttpServletRequest request,HttpSession session, Model model) {
```

I need the methods to be called in the same order as listed above. But the third method is called, before the second one.
Need your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring is using Java Reflection for getting list of methods. In most cases it's quite unpredictable in terms of JDK.

The most common workaround is to replace @ModelAttribute with corresponding model in controller's handler.

```
@RequestParam("/example/view")
public ModelAndView view(HttpServletRequest request, Model model /*probably some more parameters*/){
       model.put("awardCommand", getAwardCommand());
       model.put("achievementCommand", getAchievementCommand());
       ///... TODO put other
}
```

Comment: But if you have this commands in another controller it would be nice to inject them (not statically) for using AOP security allowing a more polymorphic behavior based on user rights. The problem is that you cannot get it ordered.